# PHP code protector

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, zend

We are about to deploy our PHP web application in different branches of our company and I am looking for PHP code encoders as to protect our PHP scripts from tampering. I know that Zend Guard is probably the most ideal tool there is, but the-power-that-be wants me to look for other alternatives.

Have you guys got any suggestions or other alternatives? I have looked around and they all promised almost the same things it gets me confused =/.

Thank's in advance for the help :D

Comment: Think this belongs on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most commonly used ones I have seen are Zend as you mentioned and [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/). These seem to be the ones most supported by hosting providers etc.

Comment: I've heard good things too about ionCube, thank's for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

I've always worked with the Zend solutions, and never been disapointed.

AND a major Point, if your corporate is not to greedy, you can buy a support and a complete Development suit and Production Environnement.

Comment: Will propose it for sure, thx :)